# how to use diff command in conditional statements and in loops

Tags: bash

I've created a script which recursively reads a path and prints its directory, and subdirectory into a csv file to write into excel columns. Now I want to modify this script such that first it will recursively read a path and print its content and then find the recursive difference of this path along with another path and I want to print if any directory is changed or not.

First code:

```
find path1 | while read file; do
  if [[ -d "$file" ]]; then
    echo $file > out.csv
  else
    echo...
  fi
done
```

and second code is:

```
diff -rq $path1 $path2 | while read file1; do
  if [[ "$file" != ]]; then
    echo Changed >> out.csv
  else
    echo no >> out.csv
  fi
done
```

Now I want to merge these codes such that fist it will recursively prints all content of path1 in csv file, then compare both paths and print changed if difference occur.

Answer (score 1):

It's not overly clear what you're trying to accomplish.   Your first part can be simplified to a single line:

```
find path1 -type d > out.csv
```

which only finds directories.   (Note that the use of `>` overwrites `out.csv`, so previous contents don't matter (you made a mistake with that in your example)).

For you second part, you could do:

```
diff <( cd path1 && find . -type d ) <( cd path2 && find . -type d )
```

This grabs all the directories in path1, and all the directories in path2, and would output the difference in standard diff format...

I'm using [process substition](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution)  `<( )` so bash treats the output as files.   Also the cd to `path1` or `path2` before the `find` prevents find from outputting `path1/` or `path2/` in its results (otherwise every line would be different).   You could do something similar with `sed` to strip off the path names.

---

If on the otherhand, your goal is to learn bash loops, you would do this as follows:

```
rm out.csv
find path | while read file; do 
    [[ -d $file ]] && echo $file >> out.csv
done

cat out.csv | while read file; do 
    [[ -e path2/${file#path1/} ]] || echo "file changed: $file"
done
```

Note that unlike the former example, this does not print any paths in path2 that are not in path1.

Here, I used `${file#path1/}`, which strips `path1/` from the front of each filename (as you're now looking in `path2`).

Hope this helps.